# Not able to add a custom authenticator to Keycloak

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak, redhat

I have to bring in a Mobile number/OTP authentication in Keycloak. I  tried using two custom authenticators which I got from the internet but both don't work. The error is:

```
 [org.jboss.modules.define] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Failed to define class com.sid.keycloakauthenticator.MobileAuthenticationFactory in Module "deployment.keycloak-authenticator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/sid/keycloakauthenticator/MobileAuthenticationFactory (Module "deployment.keycloak-authenticator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from Service Module Loader): org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/browser/UsernamePasswordFormFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

The custom authenticator I use is from the RedHat blog

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/10/23/use-mobile-numbers-for-user-authentication-in-keycloak/

I could see many users reporting similar issues, but nobody could provide a solution.
Can someone help me?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your code/configuration files also. Because if you've done everything like that tutorial, it should work.